# How to check if it the input EOF(ctrl + D) in C

Tags: c, input, eof

I have to check, will I input (ctrl +D) in this code

```
char octets_array[octets_number][128];
  for(line_counter =0; line_counter < octets_number; line_counter++)


{
printf("Please enter octet: ");
scanf("%s",octets_array[line_counter]);
}
```

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: scanf returns eof if it encounters one, so just check the returned value from it

Comment: Do you care about white-space as part of the check?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [`scanf` manual page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), check for `EOF` return code:

```
{
    printf("Please enter octet: ");
    ret_code = scanf("%s",octets_array[line_counter]);
    if (ret_code == EOF)
        puts("Ctrl+D or other end of file");
    else
        puts("Thank you for the input");
}
```

If the standard input is redirected to read from a file, `scanf` will return `EOF` after it unsuccessfully tries to read another word from the file.

If the standard input is not redirected, `scanf` will return `EOF` when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> on Windows).

Note: when it returns `EOF`, there is no data in the output variable `octets_array`. It contains either garbage or a previous value; in any case, the data there should not be used.